# Can I dispatch luggage during a connection?

Tags: air-travel, transit, luggage

I'll be travelling from Cancun with a connection in Atlanta, endpoint is Brazil. I'm allowed to dispatch 2 x 32kg luggage, and my connection in Atlanta will last more or less 10 hours.

I couldn't find any information on the company's site (Delta Airlines).

My question is: can I check one bag (Cancun -> Brazil) and then check another one in Atlanta (Atlanta -> Brazil) ?

Answer (score 1):

Because you have to claim and recheck bags when transiting through the USA, you could add your second checked bag at that point.  Delta has a baggage counter after you clear immigration and customs in Atlanta.  Just tell them you are tired of carrying your "carry on" bag and want to check it through.

Likewise if you are planning on picking up more stuff in Atlanta, you can likely check the bag at the check in counters as well.  As long as you are not exceeding your baggage allowance, you should be OK.  It is not really any different than gate checking an oversized carry-on bag.

Comment: `you have to claim and recheck bags when transiting through the USA` -- This is not accurate for an international connection. Because the final destination is outside of the US, the luggage will *not* be picked up in the US to clear customs.

Comment: You do claim your baggage for customs inspection when transiting through the USA.  http://www.atlanta-airport.com/internationalterminal/passenger/types.html (number 3)

Comment: I didn't when I flew from Mexico to London through Atlanta in February, or from London to Mexico through Atlanta on the return.

Comment: You were lucky.

Comment: I don't think luck has anything to do with it. I tried to retrieve my luggage, and couldn't. It's their policy, as I was informed when I inquired. The web site you link to is inaccurate and/or incomplete.

Comment: @Flimzy, there is a procedure called "International to International" applied at some US airports, where international-international checked baggage bypasses customs inspection.  Your bag will receive a very bright orange tag with "ITI: DO NOT RETAIN IN THE UNITED STATES" printed on it at the check in stage.
However it is far from uniform and indeed many airlines do not use this procedure. I am aware that DFW and MIA will accept this, I did not know that ATL was one.